# WebIO is not being detected by Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to open a Jupyter Notebook file in classic Jupyter Notebook interface. I am attempting to create an interective app that uses Julia programming language in interactive codes. For that I am trying to use the Interact library, because I know it features things such as buttons, sliders, etc. It requires the WebIo extension to be installed. However, from what I have experienced so far, Jupyter notebook does not detect the WebIO extension.

I tried following the instructions at https://juliagizmos.github.io/WebIO.jl/stable/gettingstarted/ and at https://juliagizmos.github.io/WebIO.jl/stable/troubleshooting/not-detected/. In the last link I found that another extension needed to be install and I found more information in this link (https://juliagizmos.github.io/WebIO.jl/latest/providers/ijulia/). I tried executing this command in my Windows prompt and it had apperently been succesful. When executing the command suggested at the second link, I got an error in the Julia REPL saying that WebIO extension for Jupyter Lab must be installed through Python or Conda, which I had already done.
I am also a bit confused as to how I can check to see if the extension is enabled.
I believe the problem has to do either with the installation of IJulia or the pip installation of WebIO. I rarely use pip, so I don't know if I did it correctly.

Thank you.